# Issues creating users Moodle's REST API

Tags: postman, moodle

I'm being tasked with automating some tasks with a Moodle installation with a program such as n8n.  I've been having success with a lot of different hurdles up until this one.  I am trying to use POST requests with Moodle's REST API to create users that are added to a central database.  Previously this was achieved with some python code and sending the JSON in the body of the request.  I have a sandbox environment I'm performing my testing in, but I can't seem to get Moodle to allow me to create a user through it's API.

I've followed the documentation for configuring and setting up the services, tokens, and authorizing users.  Here is what I'm currently sending to the route:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "testusername",
      "password": "Welcome1!",
      "firstname": "testfirstname",
      "lastname": "testlastname",
      "email": "testemail@example.com",
      "idnumber": "JSHL",
      "description": "Active",
      "auth": "manual",
      "lang": "en_us"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is what I'm getting back in response:

```
{
    "exception": "invalid_parameter_exception",
    "errorcode": "invalidparameter",
    "message": "Invalid parameter value detected",
    "debuginfo": "Missing required key in single structure: users"
}
```

This is the URL that I'm sending it too:

```
https://moodle.xxxxxxxx.com/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=47397a4ade5a6ea1157856a8f4a1ba46&wsfunction=core_user_create_users&moodlewsrestformat=json
```

Response status is 200

and the response headers are as follows:

```
Date : Tue, 21 Nov 2023 13:06:25 GMT
Server : Apache
Cache-Control : private, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0
Expires : Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma : no-cache
Accept-Ranges : none
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Keep-Alive : timeout=5, max=100
Connection : Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding : chunked
Content-Type : application/json
```

As far as I can tell the users key is in there, and this is the exact same format of how the previous script was sending data to it.  What am I missing here?  I'm using Postman to test my requests as well, if that helps at all.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the actual request and response from the postman console, not just the request and response body? You're missing a ton of information like the URL, request parameters, response status and response headers. Thanks

Comment: I provided that info now, thanks for the recommendation